# CustomCalendar Dates

Tags: android, android-calendar

I am done with customCalendar for my Project .
But I want to show just dates from current date to exact same of that date of previous month...no navigation for previous month and next month.

i.e. **today** is **27th of October 2017** then calendar will dispplay dates from **27th of September** to **27th of October**

Then if current date will be 1st of November then it will display from 
**1st October** to **1st November**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: have a look at my Sample Project you will get what every possible solution there.!
https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Date-Picker-Example-

Comment: You should post your code.

Answer (score 0):

For API level >= 11

```
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 0):

use This Method method to get last date days.!
and if you want to perform more things try my git example code [Date Example Code Tutorial](https://github.com/AtifAbbAsi19/Date-Picker-Example-)

```
   String SAMPLE_TIME_FORMAT_STRING="2017-10-07 11:22:33";

        public static final String SAMPLE_DATE_FORMAT = "yyyy-MM-dd";//;"DD/MM/YY";//"yyyy-MM-dd";

  public static String getLastDate(String dateString, int days) throws ParseException {

        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DateAndMonth.SAMPLE_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH).parse(dateString);
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTime(date);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, -days);
        Date newDate = calendar.getTime();
        calendar.setTime(newDate);

        return date_string;
    }
```